# How to convert XLA_GPU into GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and my GPU is GTX850M. I'm using nvidia drivers 430.50, `CUDA 10.1` ,`CuDNN 9.0` and `tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0`. When I try getting available devices in tensorflow with

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

I'm getting this out

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 2293723676390825589,
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 15287372432461854293
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 10399216684927698454
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"]
```

I can use the XLA_GPU for basic applications(i.e. tensorflow constant production) but I can't train a neural network. How can I convert XLA_GPU into GPU for train deep neural networks?

Answer (score 0):

Your output says that, there was issue with `Tensorflow GPU` installation.

> I'm using nvidia drivers 430.50, CUDA 10.1 ,CuDNN 9.0 and
> tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0.

According to [Tensorflow tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), `tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0` requires `CUDA-10.0` and `cuDNN-7.4`, with this combination you can use GPU on your device.

*`Note:`* If a non-GPU version of the package is installed, the function would also return `False`. Use `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` to validate if TensorFlow was build with CUDA support.

Simple workaround to use gpu is, if you can use Anaconda to install tensorflow-gpu, then it will install cuda and cudnn for you in same conda environment as tensorflow-gpu. You can create a virtual environment using conda as shown below

```
conda create --name tf python=3.8
conda activate tf  # activate tf environment
pip install tensorflow # install latest version of Tensorflow 2.4
import tensorflow
```